# Voltage drop on amplifier signal after LED switches on

Tags: electrical-engineering, power-electronics, electronics, electronic-filters, microelectronics

[image: circuit]

Circuit above shows my design for amplifying PIR sensor signal, which I then feed to Arduino and based off this signal I switch a LED on.

Both, the LED and PIR sensor, are on the same voltage rail (9V), but the op-amps are on a 5V rail.

Now the problem is that, when a LED switches ON it interferences with the amplified signal of the PIR sensor as shown below (red dot on the first image is where it is measured from).

[image: Amplified PIR sensor output]

So why is that?

Please note that this project is for educational purposes and I know that I could buy a ready PIR module with amplification. If you see anything I could of done differently, please let me know.

Comment: Can't you export a graphic from your schematic capture tool rather than taking a screenshot? It would certainly be easier to read. Can you provide a link to the datasheet for the op amps? Where is the 5V for the op amps coming from? the Arduino?

Comment: Absolutely agree with you, I should of taken the snip of that, was rushing somewhere and had to post on my phone. The OP-amp is the MCP602 (dual opamp package). Yes, the 5V is coming from Arduino and 9V is from the battery

Comment: Also note that if I switch the PIR to be powered by the 5V arduino this issue is no longer present. Why is that?

Comment: @Marcin22, information such as MCP602, 5V Arduino is best to captured in the body of the question. Some readers might not see this information, in the comment section.